# Standard Visitor UK Visa from USA (Indian National) - Sending documents for family

Tags: visas, usa, uk, standard-visitor-visas, family

We are a family of 4 Visiting UK this summer.  We have submitted our application online, have our interview scheduled in next couple of weeks.

I have a question regarding sending the documents to VFS services in New York.  Should I buy 4 different shipping labels - one for each applicant or can I send all the documents and passport for 4 of us in one shipping label / envelope?